# XML Parsing Root Node with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have this XML file. I want to parse it to obtain only **Example1** and **Example2** of  in root node, with Javascript. If I use `getElementsByTagName('author')`, i have in output all author value. What can i do ?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore>
  <author>Example1</author>
  <author>Example2</author>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("bookstore > author")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll('bookstore > author')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) as @Phylogenesis suggested in comments.

Or you can check the `parentNode` or `parentElement` property, e.g.

```javascript
var authors = document.getElementsByTagName('author');
for (var i = 0; i < authors.length; ++i) {
    if (authors[i].parentNode == 'bookstore') {
        // process author
    }
}
```